# Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V in disabled forked mode

Tags: grails, groovy, jasper-reports, itext, cobertura

I'm trying to use `code-coverage plugin` in  `Grails 2.3.5`. I added the plugin to the `BuildConfig` and as code-coverage plugin does not support the `forked` mode I had disabled it in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: false,
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```

When I run my integration tests which have jasper related functionality, following error is given:

```
|  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:597)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:399)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdfStream(JasperExportManager.java:191)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(JasperExportManager.java:527)
```

But the test cases run without error when the forked mode is enabled.

I tried resolving the issue by generating the `dependency report` and found that in both modes (forked mode enabled and disabled) the project is using the same version of `itext 2.1.7.js2`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could it be that when forked mode is disabled, it's either not including iText in the classpath, or including a more recent version of the lib (2.1.7 was the last version to use `com.lowagie` as the root package, subsequent versions use `com.itextpdf`)?